# Pivot/reshape DataFrame without existing explicit index

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, data-wrangling

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
            var value
0           a   11
1           a   12
2           a   13
3           b   21
4           b   22
5           b   23
6           c   31
7           c   32
8           c   33
```

This is in long format, and I want to go to wide format, transforming the value for the column `var` into columns, like this:

```
            a  b  c
0           11 21 31
1           12 22 33
2           31 32 33
```

The problem is that I do not have an explicit column for what would be the new index, so I cannot use `pivot()`.

I imagine that if I create a new column that counts the nth occurrence of a value for a given `var`, I can use that as my new index for `pivot()`:

```
            i  var value
0           0  a   11
1           1  a   12
2           2  a   13
3           0  b   21
4           1  b   22
5           2  b   23
6           0  c   31
7           1  c   32
8           2  c   33
```

How do I do that? The issue is I don't know the terminology so it's hard to look up. Also, if there is any better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Check `No10` in dupe.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, that's it!